# How to import html file into markdown with GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm creating a gatsby site with pages generated from markdown. Currently, each markdown file is in a separate directory. Also within that directory is a `.html` file. Is there a way I can use that html file in the markdown, not as a code snippet but as actual html?

For example, if my markdown file was:

```
This is markdown

import:bar.html
```

and `bar.html` was:

```
<div>This is html</div>
```

the output would be:

```
<p>This is markdown</p>
<div>This is html</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using an iframe and writing a local plugin which moves the html file specified by the iframe to the public folder, allowing it to be rendered by the iframe.